# How would I change the date format in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

How do I change the date format in Empathy 2.32.1? The default format is along the lines of:

`28/12/10 19:11:06`

which is huge in a chat winodw, I'm just after a simple time display if I can.

Comment: If the option is not available from the configuration interface please consider filing a bug report with the feature request at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+filebug .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version that's in Maverick is 2.32.1 and this doesn't yet have a localised datetime, but according to this mailing list thread it looks like it will base the timedate in future on the system's locale:

http://www.mail-archive.com/telepathy@lists.freedesktop.org/msg04306.html

There is also the complexity that the datetime in 2.32 should be translatable, but it doesn't appear in any of the po files so it's not really translatable at the moment.

Looks like we have to wait for empathy to clean up it's datetime bugs first, please report or add to the existing bugs mentioned in the mailing list link above. You could technically recompile empathy, but that's something for an advanced user.